# How to get all elements in a nested list where the first element of each list is a particular number?

Tags: list, recursion, prolog

I'm new to Prolog and I am having trouble with recursion and nested lists.

I want a predicate called `getCommon(Number, List, X)` which does the following:

```
getCommon(2, [[2,3], [2,5], [3,5]], X).
X = [[2,3], [2,5]].
```

I tried this but it returns an empty list and I am very confused as to why:

```
getCommon(_,[],_).
getCommon(Elem, [PointsH|PointsT], CommonPoints):-
    nth0(0, PointsH, CurrElem),
    (CurrElem = Elem -> append(CommonPoints,[PointsH],NewCommonPoints) ;append(CommonPoints,[],NewCommonPoints)),
    getCommon(Elem, PointsT, NewCommonPoints).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not work because the recursion base case is not well defined and also because predicate [append/3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=append/3) is not properly used. Try the following code:

```
get_common(_, [], []).

get_common(K, [[K,Y]|Points], [[K,Y]|Rest]) :- 
    get_common(K, Points, Rest).

get_common(K, [[X,_]|Points], Rest) :- 
    dif(K,X), 
    get_common(K, Points, Rest).
```

Examples:

```
?- get_common(2, [[2,3], [3,2], [2,5], [3,7]], Common).
Common = [[2, 3], [2, 5]] ;
false.

?- get_common(3, [[2,3], [3,2], [2,5], [3,7]], Common).
Common = [[3, 2], [3, 7]] ;
false.

?- get_common(2, [[2,3], [K,2], [2,5], [3,7]], Common).
K = 2,
Common = [[2, 3], [2, 2], [2, 5]] ;
Common = [[2, 3], [2, 5]],
dif(K, 2) ;
false.
```